# Rectangle draw and print method

Tags: c++

I have an assignment where I am supposed to draw a rectangle shape, the way is to specify two points in a plane, draw two horizontal and two vertical lines. We are supposed to use the Point class in the Rectangle class.

I have the assignment instructions `.h` (point class), `.cpp` (Point class), `.h` (Rectangle class), `.cpp` (Rectange class) and the main. I didn't do too much in main but specified what should be done.  He wants a rectangle drawn with the outline consisting of the `y`'s or the character `y`.

I think everything is good in the `.h` (point class), `.cpp` (Point class), `.h` (Rectangle class), but I am having issues with the draw method and print method of the Rectangle `.cpp`, the instructor said to just use a temp variable for the origin in the draw method or something like that,

Also not sure about the print method in the `.cpp` Rectangle file, would appreciate help here. Tried to compile but all hell broke loose, any explanation/example would help a lot.

Point.h

```
//Point.h
#include <iostream.h>
/* The Point class Header file (Point.h) */
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

class Point {

private:
    double x,y;//x and y are private variables

public:    
    Point(int x, int y):x(x),y(y){}//use initialization list    
    double getX() const; //Getters    
    double getY() const;    
    void setX(double x);  //Setters    
    void setY(double y);    //Setters

    void print()const;
    //Overload '+' operator
    const Point operator +(const Point & rt)const;
    //Overload '-' operator
    const Point operator - (const Point &rt)const;

    Point operator +=(Point & rt);
    Point operator -=(Point & rt);
    //Overload '==' operator comparing two points

    int operator ==(Point &rt);
    int operator <(Point &rt);
    int operator >(Point &rt);
    int operator <=(Point &rt);
    int operator >=(Point &rt); 

};
/* POINT_H */
#endif
```

Point .cpp

```
//the Point.cpp file
#include "Point.h"
#include<iostream>    
using namespace std;    
//Getters
double Point::getX()const {return x;}
double Point::getY()const {return y;}

//setters    
void Point::setX(double x) {this->x=x;}
void Point::setY(double y) {this->y=y;}

//Public functions
void Point::print()const{
    cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ")" << endl;
}

//overloading '+' operator
const Point Point::operator+(const Point & rt) const{
return Point(x + rt.x, y + rt.y);
}

const Point Point::operator-(const Point & rt) const{
return Point(x - rt.x, y - rt.y);
}

Point Point::operator+=(Point & rt){
return Point(x+=rt.x, y+=rt.y);
}

int Point::operator ==(Point & rt){
return (x == rt.x && y==rt.y);
}

int Point::operator <(Point & rt){
return (x < rt.x && y<rt.y);
}

int Point::operator >(Point & rt){
return (x > rt.x && y>rt.y);
}

int Point::operator <=(Point & rt){
return (x <= rt.x && y<=rt.y);
}

int Point::operator >=(Point & rt){
return (x >= rt.x && y>=rt.y);
}
//;   
//;    
//END POINT.CPP
```

Rectangle h file

```
#ifndef RECTANGLE_H    
#define RECTANGLE_H
#include <iostream.h>   
#include "Point.h"    
class Rectangle {

private:    
    Point origin;
    Point corner;

public:
    Rectangle (const Point & or, const Point & cr):origin(or),corner(cr) {}
    // void move(int dx, int dy);    
    void draw();
    void print()const;
};      
#endif  /* RECTANGLE_H */
```

Rectangle .cpp file

```
/* The Rectangle.cpp file) */
#include "Point.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;    
// Public Functions
 void Rectangle::print() const
{
     cout<<"(" <<origin <<"," <<corner << ")" <<endl;
}  

void Rectangle::draw()    
 {    
      Point temp=origin;      //store origin in temp object
      while (temp.getX() < corner.getX())  {
      putch('y');    
     }
     /* int temp=origin;    
       for (int x = temp.getX(); x < center.getX(); x++) {
        Point pt1 (x, temp.getY());
        Point pt2 (x, center.getY());
       pt1(6,4);
      //    move to p1 // not sure how to do this
        putCH ('y');
       pt2(30,15);
       //   move to p2  //not sure how to do this
        putCH ('y');
  }

   for (int y = lowerRight.getY(); y < upperLeft.getY(); y++) {
          Point pt1 (origin.getX(),y);
          Point pt2 (corner.getX(),y);
           pt1(6,4);
          //move to p1  //not sure how to do this
          putCH('y');
          pt2(30,15);
         // move to p2  //not sure how to do this
          putCH ('y');
   }*/   
//return 0;   
}//;
```

MAIN

```
 #include "Point.h"
 #include "Rectangle.h"
 #include <iostream>
 #include <conio.h>
 using namespace std;

 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {
      //char y;        
      Point p1(6, 4), p2(30, 15);

      //cout<<"\n the origin of Rectangle is at:  ";
      //p1.print();
      //cout<<"\n the opposite corner of rect is at:";
      //p2.print();

      Rectangle r1(p1,p2);        
      r1.draw();        
      clrscr();        
      gotoxy(1,20);        
      //r1.print();        
      getch();
      return 0;       
    } //;
    //END OF MAIN
```

Comment: Two tips here. 1. Take the first line of the error message from the compiler and fix that. 2. Do not type the whole lot in and hope for the best. Do it by tying in a few lines and compile, When you are more confident then you are able to type in more lines between complications.

Answer (score 1):

I could see one C++ specific issue:  you did not overload `"<<"` operator on Point.  First please do that.

Secondly, which compiler are you using?

```
clrscr(); gotoxy();
```

are not part of standard C+++.
If your compiler supports them, well and good. 
Otherwise, you need to look for alternatives.

Good convention: avoid

> using namespace std;

Instead, write

```
   std::cout 
   std::endl;
```

etc

I did not go through your actual logic. 
   Which is actually your assignment - isnt't it?